# How do I know who is talking?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In Mass Effect 3 multiplayer, I have run into a few screaming 12-year-olds. And while they are just a delight to talk to, and so well mannered, on occasion I feel that their mature and thoughtful discussion might distract me from the tasks at hand. In the ME3 multiplayer interface, is there any way to tell who is talking so that I may know whom I should mute?

By the way, I am on Xbox 360.

Comment: What platform are you playing on?  The answer may vary a bit.

Comment: +1 for effective use of sarcasm and proper usage of the word 'whom' :-).

Comment: @agent86 You're right, I didn't think about that. I'm playing it on Xbox 360.

Comment: @Ktash, I can't check until this evening, but usually on the Xbox 360, pressing "Back" will bring up a list, and the active speaker will have a speaker icon by their name.

Comment: +1 for the polite phrasing. (Bryson already gave you a point for the sarcasm :-)

Comment: @agent86 Yeah, it brings up the list but I didn't see any mics unfortunately :/

Comment: @Ktash +1 for the awesome choice to call it their "discussion" "mature and thoughtful" lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the mission launch screen, there is a little speaker icon by each players name... it is red if they have no mic, blue if they do have one. When someone is talking it is blue with sound waves coming off of it. Get them talking before the mission launches, mute them there and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  After a few hours I found this post: http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/7577844.page

> Make a party and invite no one.

This post was written while the game was in beta, but I didn't find any other useful solution. IMO, the "back-button solution" is kind of annoying.

Comment: This is a good solution, but also disables my other teammates from being able to talk. I'd like to avoid it if I can because occasionally you do meet good people to talk with. I will mark as best in a while if it turns out there is no way to know. :)

Comment: I see EA has locked this solution tightly behind the authentication required curtain.  Wouldn't want trade secrets about how to enjoy their games more efficiently leaking out.